# Modificar correo de destino al envíar mail en PHP

Tags: php

estoy desarrollando un pequeño formulario de contacto el cual ya funciona, envía un correo con el asunto y el mensaje . El problema es que siempre que me llega un correo llega con la siguiente direccion: noreply@farmaciassanasana.com.mx
que la defino en el php.ini de la siguiente manera:

```
    [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.farmaciassanasana.com.mx
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 35

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = noreply@farmaciassanasana.com.mx

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
```

Existe alguna manera de que en esa parte vaya el correo de la persona que esta enviando el mensaje. De momento el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 <?php 

require 'vistas/mail.view.php';

    define("correo", "soporte1@farmaciassanasana.com.mx");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $de=filter_var($_POST['de'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $asunto=filter_var($_POST['asunto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $mensaje=filter_var($_POST['mensaje'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        if (mail(correo, $asunto, $mensaje)) {
            echo "Correo enviado satisfactoriamente";
        }else{
            echo "Fallo al enviar el mensaje";
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Ojala puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que te refieres a la dirección del remitente y no a la de destino.

El cuarto parámetro (el cual es opcional) que recibe la función [mail()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) permite agregar otras cabeceras como en este caso la dirección del remitente:

En el sitio web de php hay un ejemplo con este parámetro (definido en la variable $cabeceras):

```
<?php
$para      = 'nobody@example.com';
$titulo    = 'El título';
$mensaje   = 'Hola';
$cabeceras = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
?>
```

Comment: Gracias, me fue demasiado útil tu respuesta.